# Flutter bug: card widget with linear gradient on image has bleeding edges

Tags: flutter, dart, user-interface

I have encountered an issue whilst trying to display an image (`CachedNetworkImage`) inside of a `Card` with `LinearGradient` over the image. The image is "bleeding" through the gradient at the bottom and left side of the Card. I don't know what is causing this, I have tried expanding, changing the size and aligning the items in the stack, but to no avail. It seems like a Flutter UI bug to me. Does anyone know how to solve this? Or maybe what different approach can I take to display this gradient over an image that will not show this visual defect? I am attaching screenshots with Cards with photos and with red background to visualize the issue.

[image]

```dart
class CharacterTile extends StatelessWidget {
  const CharacterTile(
      {super.key, required this.character, required this.isLocked});

  final CharacterModel character;
  final bool isLocked;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return InkWell(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12.0),
      onTap: () {},
      child: Card(
        color: Colors.transparent,
        surfaceTintColor: Colors.transparent,
        shape:
            RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12.0)),
        clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
        child: Stack(
          children: [
            CachedNetworkImage(
              fit: BoxFit.cover,
              width: double.infinity,
              height: double.infinity,
              imageUrl: character.profilePictureUrl,
            ),
            Container(
              clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
              alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
              width: double.infinity,
              height: double.infinity,
              decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                gradient: LinearGradient(
                  begin: Alignment.topCenter,
                  end: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                  colors: [
                    Colors.transparent,
                    Colors.black,
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```